# Flex table - how to sync cell heights

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a flex table where each row is composed of cells and cells may have nested cells inside. It works fine if we assume that nested cell height is constant.
[image]

Unfortunately if some nested cell height is different, table breaks up.

[image]
I would like to have table in which such row looks like this:
[image]
Is there any way to fix it without changing table structure (and without using html tables)? Pure css solution would be great but I am afraid it is not possible. In that case what is the best/easiest approach using javascript?

Code:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex: 33%;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.cell .cell {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="cell">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="cell">B1</div>
    <div class="cell">B2</div>
    <div class="cell">B3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="cell">C1</div>
    <div class="cell">Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text</div>
    <div class="cell">C3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I _highly_ recommend you use CSS grid, or even just normal tables (if the data is tabular, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your structure a bit and came up with this solution via css grids. Borders are not added and let me know if they are needed!

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(200px, 300px));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 200px);
}

.cellA {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.cellB1, .cellC1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.cellB2, .cellC2 {
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.cellB3, .cellC3 {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell cellA">A</div>
    <div class="cell cellB1">B1</div>
    <div class="cell cellB2">B2</div>
    <div class="cell cellB3">B3</div>
    <div class="cell cellC1">C1</div>
    <div class="cell cellC2">Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text</div>
    <div class="cell cellC3">C3</div>
</div>
```